# How can I treat an underlying byte array as an array of shorts? Or ints? Or longs?

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I am an embedded engineer, working in Java.  I need to communicate with devices, and frequently I need to massage buffers into the form needed by or produced by some hardware.

I have spent considerable time searching the net (and this site) looking for an answer for how to treat a buffer of bytes as a buffer of larger elements.  There are many responses, but they always boil down to either (1) use ByteBuffer or (2) do the conversion manually.

The problem is, no conversion is needed... the underlying byte array contains valid shorts, with the correct endianness.  I don't want the expense of copying an array of bytes to an identical array of shorts.  All I want to do is convince the Java compiler to see them as the type I'm interested in.

I don't have a lot of experience with ByteBuffer, but I that was the first path I went down.  What I discovered is that if I have a ByteBuffer and I call its asShortBuffer() function, the resulting ShortBuffer has no backing array... I can't call array() on it, which is what I need.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Assuming that this is the case -- and it's what I was expecting to hear, based on the searching I've done -- does anybody know of a package that has tools to work around it?  Maybe a brief dive into JNI, just enough to pass back a different type signature?

Comment: The reason I keep pushing is because I can state categorically that embedded engineers with needs similar to mine *do not* do fine with extraneous copies... there are circumstances where extra array copies are totally unacceptable.  I'm a long-time C/C++ programmer and I've been programming in Java intensively for 4 years now.  I really like it.... most of the time... but then I run across something like this, or the lack of unsigned data types, that really makes Java a trial for doing embedded work.

Comment: Basically you can't, aside from using ByteBuffer, et al.  Unless you write your own JNI routines do to what you want.  (Not clear why ByteBuffer doesn't work for you, though.)

Comment: (Keep in mind that Java is not commonly used for embedded programming (at a level below Android), at least not without considerable JNI involvement.)

Comment: (I have done the direct mapping in the past, but I did it by controlling the innards of the JVM interpreter and JITC.)

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound like an option for me, really.  Yes, I realize Java isn't commonly used for embedded work... yet sometimes it is, and wish a couple of these small issues (unsigned primitives, buffer casting) could be fixed, because otherwise Java is an excellent embedded language.  The project I've been working on could never have come as far and as fast if I hadn't been working in Java under Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually need a ShortBuffer?  Why not just use the various get/put methods on the ByteBuffer to read/write short, int, and other values from/to the underlying byte array?

Comment: Again, I don't want to extract shorts or ints from the array... I want be able to pass the entire array to a function that requires an array of shorts.

Comment: Then I am afraid you are out of luck.  If there a reason you want to deal with arrays as opposed to a ByteBuffer?  A direct ByteBuffer is essentially an interface to read/write a blob of unmanaged memory.  It's about as close as you can get to a low-level C-style array.

Comment: The hardware I'm dealing with knows nothing about ByteBuffers; it wants arrays of values.

Comment: But you're working in Java.  Are you passing arrays to external native code?

Comment: No, I'm writing them to sockets.

Comment: If you're writing them to sockets, why can't you just write a byte array regardless of what values are encoded within?  I would think the only meaningful difference would be the length, but you can just write that out manually.

Comment: OK, a very good point.  The answer is that I'm also using some existing library routines for dealing with some of the hardware, and those routines want be be passed arrays of various types.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know your usecase, but the question does not imply that you actually need to convert the whole byte array to an array of shorts / ints / longs (otherwise, the ByteBuffer or manuall conversion would be OK).

If you only need to *treat* any value in that array as a short/int/long, all you need to do is assign it and the upcast will be implicit:

```
int i = byteArray[x]; // works like a charm
```

In the same way, you can pass any value there to a method that expects a `long` or whatever without any need for casting.

---

Edit:

As a response to your comment, you can make use of the array covariance only if you can afford to use object wrappers instead of primitives (this implies you control the code in the method you mentioned):

```
// needs to be Number because Byte does not inherit from Short
myMethod(Number[] numbers) {   // do something with number.shortValue() ...
```

And you can call it using:

```
myMethod(new Byte[10]);
```

But this would be even less acceptable than converting a `byte[]` to a `short[]`, I assume.

Comment: Sorry to have been unclear.  I have an array of bytes, and I need to pass it to a function that accepts an array of shorts.  I don't want to copy the buffers each time... this isn't quite a zero-copy system, but I'd prefer not to introduce completely unnecessary copies.

Comment: Re-reading, this is an interesting point that I wasn't aware of... thanks.  It doesn't really help me with this problem, but it's good to know.

Comment: The flaw with this is that it will only use the 8-bits in the array value instead of the whole 16/32/64 bits which is trying to be solved by this problem.

Comment: @Jiro117: I'm not sure I got that: the flaw with... what ?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, not that useful, then.  But thanks for answering.

Comment: If you do something like "int i = byteArray[x];" you will only get values in the range of -128 to 127. I believe what EQvan is looking for is closer to "short i = ((byteArray[x] & 0xff) >> 8) | (byteArray[x+1] & 0xff);" (depending on endianness).

Comment: @Jiro117: I now see what you mean; but I did not understand that from the question: you're assuming that he wants to build shorts from pairs of bytes, but what I think is that he simply wants to treat each byte as a short value, which is just widening (not even upcasting).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing array() from the ShortBuffer, you could simply use a bulk [get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ShortBuffer.html#get%28short%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) into an existing array. Same could be applied to other data types.

Comment: I just had a look at the bulk get() function.  It makes it clear that a copy operation is being performed.  The buffer I have contains perfectly valid contents and doesn't need any conversion or copying... if I can convince Java of that fact.

Comment: It copies the values over but avoids allocating a new array as it will simply use the existing array and overwrite its values. There is no way to treat an array of bytes like a different type of array because they are different classes both inheriting from the Object class.

Comment: Yes, I realize they are different classes... that's the very point I'm trying to deal with. Is there really no way to tell Java that the data is of the type I know it to be, rather than the type it thinks?

Comment: Unfortunately, Java will not let you do that. You can't treat them as two different types both pointing to the same memory. You will at some point have to perform a copy if you want to get the byte[] into a short[]. Even if you try to cast a byte[].class to a short[].class you will get a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the bytebuffer and know the endainness, you can always generate shorts/ints on the fly. You are stuck because you want to access it as an array of shorts/ints.